# Issues Accessing Samba Share using FQDN

Tags: centos, samba

I have a fresh Centos 8 server that I'm setting up for a client, and it's giving me the worst troubles with setting up network shares on the AD DC.

I've scoured google for several hours, and nothing I can dig up helps. A lot of the results are several years old, and I don't think apply to newer versions. After [several of these moments](https://xkcd.com/979/), maybe this thread will help somebody in the future.

One issue I've considered is that during domain provisioning my default NETBIOS name was `LOCALHOST` and I never changed it, so it may be causing issues resolving on other machines. I've tried changing it, but I may not be changing everything correctly as doing so causes connecting to the domain to fail entirely.

Currently I'm able to access my network server using 3 different methods, each with their own error

**1. Opening `\\OFFICE`**
Connecting to just the shortname shows all of the files & printers that are being shared, but none of them are able to connect.
Attempting to connect to one of the shares gives the error

> \\OFFICE\public is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
>
> A volume has been accessed for which a file system driver is required that has not yet been loaded.

**2. Opening `\\office.mydomain.com`**
Connecting this way allows me to access all of the network printers, however only `sysvol` and `netlogon` are accessible drives. Attempting to connect to any of the other drives gives this error

> \\office.mydomain.com\public is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
>
> Element not found.

**3. Opening `\\192.168.1.2`**
Attempting to connect using the controllers IP address works for all printers and network shares *except* for `netlogon` and `sysvol`. Attempting to open either of the default drives prompts for a login, which fails even with the `OFFICE\administrator` account.

My thesis was that the drive shares aren't actually considered part of the domain, but trying to access the locations from a non-domain account prompts for a domain login.

I also spent several hours digging into DNS thinking that could be the issue, but if the NETBIOS being `LOCALHOST` isn't a problem, I don't have any issues with the shares other than not being able to access the directories. Printers work fine, pinging the server is fine, `nslookup` returns the correct result, SSH works correctly with the domain. I'm not familiar enough with Samba to know what handles the mapping of the shares, ex. `\public`

The version of running:

```
$: smbd -V
Version 4.12.3
```

All of my directories show up properly

```
$: smbclient -L localhost -U%

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    sysvol          Disk      
    netlogon        Disk      
    public          Disk      
    share1          Disk      
    share2          Disk      
    share3          Disk      
    share4          Disk      
    users           Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba 4.12.3)
    Printer1        Printer   EPSON WF-7520 Series
    Printer2        Printer   EPSON ET-3750 Series
    Printer3        Printer   EPSON ET-3750 Series
    Printer4        Printer   Brother QL-710W
    Printer5        Printer   EPSON ET-3750 Series
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

Below are my configs

**smb.conf**

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    # Realm information
    netbios name = LOCALHOST
    realm = OFFICE.MYDOMAIN.COM
    server role = active directory domain controller
    
    disable netbios = no
    smb ports = 139 445
    
    # DNS is controlled by BIND
    server services = rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, s3fs
    
    # Work group
    workgroup = OFFICE
    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
    
    # Log from user IPs
    log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
    #log level = 5
    
    # Printing servers with Cups!
    printing = cups
    printcap name = cups
    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw
    
    # Mapped drive configs
    map archive = no
    map readonly = no
    
    # Home Directories
    logon drive = H:
    logon home = \\office.mydomaincom\users\%U
    
    # Winbindd
    winbind cache time = 10
    winbind nss info = rfc2307
    winbind use default domain = yes
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    
    template shell = /bin/bash
    template homedir = /home/%D/%U
    
    # WINS
    domain logons = yes
    preferred master = yes
    domain master = yes
    #wins support = yes
    #host msdfs = yes
    time server = yes
    
    # DNS
    dns forwarder = 192.168.1.2
    
    # Enable FreeRADIUS authorization
    ntlm auth = mschapv2-and-ntlmv2-only

# Generic system volume
[sysvol]
    path = /usr/local/samba/var/locks/sysvol
    read only = no

# Net login scripts
[netlogon]
    path = /usr/local/samba/var/locks/sysvol/office.mydomain.com/scripts
    read only = no

# Shared printers
[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba/
    printable = yes
    create mask = 0600
    browseable = no

# Share for all companies
[public]
    path = /srv/samba/public
    read only = no

[share1]
    path = /srv/samba/share1
    read only = no

[share2]
    path = /srv/samba/share2
    read only = no

[share3]
    path = /srv/samba/share3
    read only = no

[share4]
    path = /srv/samba/share4
    read only = no

# User home directory
[users]
    path = /srv/samba/home
    read only = no
```

**krb5.conf**

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = OFFICE.MYDOMAIN.COM
        dns_lookup_realm = true
        dns_lookup_kdc = true

[realms]
OFFICE.MYDOMAIN.COM = {
        default_domain = office.mydomain.com
}

[domain_realm]
    localhost = OFFICE.MYDOMAIN.COM
```

**nsswitch.conf**

```
passwd:     files winbind
group:      files winbind
netgroup:   files winbind
automount:  files winbind
services:   files winbind

# In order of likelihood of use to accelerate lookup.
shadow:     files winbind
hosts:      dns myhostname

aliases:    files
ethers:     files
gshadow:    files
# Allow initgroups to default to the setting for group.
# initgroups: files
networks:   dns
protocols:  files winbind
publickey:  files
rpc:        files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much more digging and playing around, I figured out that I had two issues at hand.

Firstly was how I was connecting to the server. `\\OFFICE`, `\\office.mydomain.com`, and `\\192.168.1.2` all *connect*, however none of them are actually recognized as fully part of the DC. I had to incorporate the NETBIOS name into the FQDN and connect to `\\localhost.office.mydomain.com`. From here all printers, *and* shares (Including `netlogon` and `sysvol`) were recognized. This might be changeable somewhere else, but this works for my needs.

Secondly was a folder permission issue,

```
$: ls -ld sysvol/
drwxrwx---+ 9 root BUILTIN\administrators 135 Jul  9 09:24 sysvol/

$: ls -ld /srv/samba
drwxrwx---. 3 root root 22 Jul  9 09:15 /srv/samba
```

I tested moving my shares into the `sysvol` share, and had no problems connecting to them at that point. So I checked the permissions on the `sysvol` share and saw that it was owned by the `BUILTIN\administrators` group, which my *shares* are owned by, however the parent folder also needs that permission, otherwise samba won't read the shares properly.

Once I figured out my shares were working while housed inside of `sysvol` I applied the permissions back to my `/srv/samba` directory, and moved them back. I'm not 100% on `sysvol` but I believe storing additional files in that share probably isn't the best idea.